# Error when executing 'perl Makefile.PL': Can't find net-snmp-config

Tags: perl, installation, snmp, dependency-management, net-snmp

I am trying to install NetSNMP-OID (version 5.0404) but when I run 'perl Makefile.PL' (in the NetSNMP-OID directory) I get the message:

```
You need to install net-snmp first (I can't find net-snmp-config) at Makefile.PL line 91.
```

After adding some checkpoints to the Makefile.PL using 'print' statements, I discovered that it was not executing the following lines (83 to 85):

```
if (lc($opts->{'insource'}) eq "true") {
        $Params{'LIBS'} = "-L../../snmplib/.libs -L../../snmplib/ " . $Params{'LIBS'};
        $Params{'CCFLAGS'} = "-I../../include " . $Params{'CCFLAGS'};
```

which is likely why it crashed at 90/91?:

```
if ($Params{'LIBS'} eq "" || $Params{'CCFLAGS'} eq "") {
        die "You need to install net-snmp first (I can't find net-snmp-config)";
    }
```

I have net-snmp installed (correctly, I think), so I'm wondering if maybe I have it in the wrong directory?  It is currently in home/ (~, i.e. ~/net-snmp-5.7.3/).

If someone with experience in Perl could explain what the first segment of code (lines 83 to 85) is doing, that would be beneficial as well!

OS: Raspbian

**EDIT:**
Notes:
`net-snmp-config` is a shell (.sh) script found directly inside the net-snmp directory (~/net-snmp-5.7.3/net-snmp-config).
Makefile.PL can be found here: [NetSNMP-OID-5.0404/Makefile.PL](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/HARDAKER/NetSNMP-OID-5.0404/Makefile.PL)

Comment: Where is net-snmp-config? Is it installed on your machine? Have you updated $PATH to include it's location?

Comment: net-snmp-config is a shell (.sh) script directly inside the net-snmp-5.7.3 directory.  And no, I have not.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the module myself, but from a quick look at the source, try

```
perl Makefile.PL --NET-SNMP-CONFIG ~/net-snmp-5.7.3/net-snmp-config
```

- `%opts` come from `GetOptions`, which parses command-line arguments ([source](https://metacpan.org/source/HARDAKER/NetSNMP-OID-5.0404/Makefile.PL#L75)).
- `%Params` are produced based on the `%opts`, the machine type, and other factors.  For example, `$Params{LIBS}` is assigned [here](https://metacpan.org/source/HARDAKER/NetSNMP-OID-5.0404/Makefile.PL#L77) by running `net-snmp-config`.

The `NET-SNMP-CONFIG` command-line option is stored into `$opts{nsconfig}`, which is then run to get the `CFLAGS` and `LIBS` necessary.

**Edit** Lines 83–85 are only one of the ways `CFLAGS` and `LIBS` can be set.  In your case, it appears that lines 77 and 79 are not able to do so, probably because they can't find `net-snmp-config`.

Comment: ...wow.  Yeah, that worked!  Despite this, mysql-snmp still cannot find NetSNMP/OID.pm, but that's another issue.  During the successful execution of Makefile.PL, it warned me that my Net-SNMP module is newer than my Perl module and that different versions very rarely work well together, so I guess I'll chase that next.  Thanks!